# Linux - Program persistanly running on port 3000

Tags: linux, upstart

I have a node server running consistently on port 3000,
so every time I kill it, it will load back.

I know which program server it is, but I don't know which program/service is responsible to restarting the server.

I did install docker lately, but I made sure docker & docker-compose are both inactive i.e. stopped.

Is there any way to find out what is the responsible program?

Update:
this is happening on only 1 server \ project.
and only happening on "nodemon" but not when I run the server with `node filename.js`

Comment: pm2 not installed

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar Yet, only [so] is equipped to answer questions about configuring *development* software, such as `node`. In this case, the OP self-solved, but I don't believe [su] would have provided a more useful answer than SO.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to find which processes or services are running on `3000`, sometimes, a simple `lsof -i:3000` should find those processes. Use, `kill -9 [pid]` to kill process.

Also, you should kill the process under the user who has created it.

Comment: yes I did, it was node server, from a folder I recognized, I just didn'u understand why was it persistently upstarting.

Answer (score 0):

just deleted, and re cloned the repo.... it is all good now :)

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18800358)

Comment: like what? sorry but I really don't know what was restarting the node server.   I solved by deleting the folder and re downloading the repo

Comment: This is to be posted as a question update if it doesn\`t solve the initial problem. Please use [the 'edit' button below your post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J66v1.png) and remove this answer.